# Magento - adding products to a bundle

Tags: magento

I was wondering if there was a maximum number of items that can be to a bundle product in Magento 1.6?

I have a product, that is a bundle and I am trying to add other products as the bundle option of 'Type'.

There are approx 250 types, but it seems that I can only add a max of about 200 items and when saving the item, there is only 104

Has ayone come across this before? Is it a Magento/browser restriction?

Thanks

Comment: Very hard to understand from your question what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: When creating a bundle product, there is an option on the left `Bundle Items`. I have created a new option `Add Option`, selected checkbox, not required and given it a name. I have then, under `Add Selection`, added 200 products. Clicking on `Add selected product(s) to Option`. All the products are then fine in the list. After saving/continue edit, the 200 items I added, only display 104 items. I have numerous times, new bundle products, each time, 104 products maximum

Comment: Has no-one ever come across this before?

Comment: I think when you have over 200 options, you should rethink the product structure, because that seems a lot.

Comment: How else could I do it? The options are to select a type. A user can select upto 5 types (which are simple products).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If the stated below is the solution, this is a Duplicate of [Magento & Big bundle products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044387)

If using php with Suhosin patch, editing the Suhosin variables

suhosin.post.max_vars
suhosin.request.max_vars

file: /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/suhosin.ini

or you could edit to your site php.ini