# Magento: Bundle items added but on reload they are empty

Tags: magento, admin, post-install

I go in and add items to a category for a bundled item. It seems it does it, and then opening again the category is empty.

How to trace this error?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Edit item - Bundle tab - Add Selected Product(s) to Option
2. Click on "Save and Continue Edit" button
3. I see a call to `/index.php/admin/catalog_product/validate/id/481/back/edit/tab/product_info_tabs_bundle_items/key/8bee606f1ce09f1f0e2b4128v379e52e/?isAjax=true` and am able to trace the Response (using Chrome's "Network" tab) with output `{"error":false}`
4. I see a call to `/index.php/admin/catalog_product/save/back/edit/tab/product_info_tabs_bundle_items/id/481/key/371758eb16ca00ac50c8ca42e90d7559/` which has no response
5. Page redirects with "The product has been saved message.".
6. The edits are not there

I am using Magento 1.6.2.

Comment: Check your system.log and exception.log file in /var/log

Comment: Yes, just found about it. Solved by editing the Suhosin variables

suhosin.post.max_vars
suhosin.request.max_vars 

file: /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/suhosin.ini

or you could add it to your site php.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by editing the Suhosin variables suhosin.post.max_vars suhosin.request.max_vars file: /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/suhosin.ini or you could add it to your site php.ini